# Parallelize an R Script

Tags: r, parallel-processing

The problem with my R script is that it takes too much time and the main solution that I consider is to parallelize it. I don't know where to start.

My code look like this:

```
n<- nrow (aa) 
output <- matrix (0, n, n)

akl<- function (dii){
        ddi<- as.matrix (dii)
        m<- rowMeans(ddi)
        M<- mean(ddi)
        r<- sweep (ddi, 1, m)
        b<- sweep (r, 2, m)
        return (b + M)  
        }
for (i in 1:n)
{
A<- akl(dist(aa[i,]))

dVarX <- sqrt(mean (A * A))

for (j in i:n)
{
    B<- akl(dist(aa[j,]))
        V <- sqrt (dVarX * (sqrt(mean(B * B))))

        output[i,j] <- (sqrt(mean(A * B))) / V        
}
}
```

I would like to parallelize on different cpus. How can I do that?
I saw the SNOW package, is it suitable for my purpose?
Thank you for suggestions,
Gab

Comment: You should calculate `dist(aa)` just once (outside loops).

Comment: the input is a matrix and my code compute something on each row (akl) and then take each rowpair to compute something different (pratically a correlation score). The output is another matrix.

Comment: please provide working example

Comment: By 'working example' ECII means something like: wrap this code in a function that takes a matrix as argument, then create a matrix, then run the function to show us the expected answer. Call the function fooSlowVersion if you want, and then we can try and write fooParallelVersion and compare easily.

Comment: @Gabelins: I didn't say calculate `akl(whatever)` once. I _said_ calculate `dist(aa)` once. And you really should construct an example.

Comment: Sorry, I have a test matrix, but I don't know how to upload it here. I'm going to add the part to create a matrix...give me seconds!

Comment: Through this you obtain a good test matrix (100x100):    a<- matrix (c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1), 100, 100)
    s<- apply (a, 2, sample)
    aa<- as.matrix (s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways in which your code could be made to run faster that I could think of:

`First:` As `@Dwin` was saying (with a small twist), you could `precompute` akl (yes, not necesarily dist, but the whole of akl).

```
# a random square matrix
aa <- matrix(runif(100), ncol=10)
n <- nrow(aa)
output <- matrix (0, n, n)

akl <- function(dii) {
    ddi <- as.matrix(dii)
    m   <- rowMeans(ddi)
    M   <- mean(m) # mean(ddi) == mean(m)
    r   <- sweep(ddi, 1, m)
    b   <- sweep(r, 2, m)
    return(b + M)
}

# precompute akl here
require(plyr)
akl.list <- llply(1:nrow(aa), function(i) {
    akl(dist(aa[i, ]))
})

# Now, apply your function, but index the list instead of computing everytime
for (i in 1:n) {
    A     <- akl.list[[i]]
    dVarX <- sqrt(mean(A * A))

    for (j in i:n) {
        B <- akl.list[[j]]
        V <- sqrt (dVarX * (sqrt(mean(B * B))))
        output[i,j] <- (sqrt(mean(A * B))) / V        
    }
}
```

This should already get your code to run faster than before (as you compute akl everytime in the inner loop) on larger matrices.

`Second:` In addition to that, you can get it faster by parallelising as follows:

```
# now, the parallelisation you require can be achieved as follows
# with the help of `plyr` and `doMC`.

# First step of parallelisation is to compute akl in parallel
require(plyr)
require(doMC)
registerDoMC(10) # 10 Cores/CPUs
    akl.list <- llply(1:nrow(aa), function(i) {
    akl(dist(aa[i, ]))
}, .parallel = TRUE)

# then, you could write your for-loop using plyr again as follows
output <- laply(1:n, function(i) {
    A     <- akl.list[[i]]
    dVarX <- sqrt(mean(A * A))

    t <- laply(i:n, function(j) {
        B <- akl.list[[j]]
        V <- sqrt(dVarX * (sqrt(mean(B*B))))
        sqrt(mean(A * B))/V
    })
    c(rep(0, n-length(t)), t)
}, .parallel = TRUE)
```

Note that I have added `.parallel = TRUE` only on the outer loop. This is because, you assign 10 processors to the outer loop. Now, if you add it to both outer and inner loops, then the total number of processers will be 10 * 10 = 100. Please take care of this.

Comment: tryed on a large matrix...the first solution is very nice! Thank you so much!

Comment: While using the first solution on a 2500 x 700 matrix I get a problem with memory size. Any help for solving?

Comment: ...one more question: with the first solution, how can I apply a plyr function to avoid the loop in calculating sqrt(mean(A*B))?

Comment: I tryed the second solution that you advice...but I get this error Warning message:
In setup_parallel() : No parallel backend registered)               Is it because I'm not using the doMC package? ..i'm on a Windows machine...

Comment: :( seems like that (and the code is a bit too much slow for my work....argh!) Thank you anyway, you were great!

Comment: sorry if I annoy you...but I'm trying it now on a linux machine with doMC and plyr...and i get the same error (No parallel backend registered)..so, now the question is: what can I do to register parallel backends?